# Triggering AjaxControlToolkit ModalPopupExtender Cancel Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender, aspwizard

My ModalPopupExtender has:

```
    CancelControlID="btnClose"

    <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" Width="50px"  />
```

btnClose can not have an OnClick event. System simply does not work if it does.

My popup form has 3 other buttons, Save. Delete and Cancel.

If any of these are used, the Wizard Next button and the Sidebar Links no longer work. They only work if btnClose is used. I assume it does something to tell the system the popup is closed. How do I make my Save / Delete / Cancel buttons do the same thing? cam I trigger a btnClose.Click?

Comment: paste your all code... this doesn't make any sense

Comment: You wouldn't want to see all my code - it is huge.

Comment: Hey @SteveStaple did you got the solution i am here also stucked at the same problem. If you got it please share it

Answer (score 1):

you can close `ModelPopupExtender` from code behind as well as from java script based up on your requirements.

C#:

```
ModalPopupExtender1.Hide();
```

Javascript:

```
$find('ModalPopupExtender1').hide(); //keep this in a function an call the same function where ever you want
```

Comment: Thanks Sunil, but Hiding the popup form is not the problem. It is hiding OK. It is not cancelling, so the form buttons on the parent form remain inactive.

Comment: if I specify one of my buttons as OKControlID, such as this one:          <asp:Button ID="btnSaveQuestions" runat="server" Text="Save Question" 
                                     OnClick="btnSaveQuestions_Click" CssClass="nonavigate" />        The function btnSaveQuestions_Click is not executed!

Comment: Adding this to by button overcame that: OnClientClick="__doPostBack(this.name, '')"

Comment: There is always more than 1 way to skin a cat. I can now work around this. I will remove the Close button and Delete button, and just retain Save (as OKControlID) and Cancel (as CancelControlID) using that OnClientClick="__doPostBack(this.name, '')". I can put the Delete button on the parent form.

Comment: I gave up on the ModalPopupExtender in the end. I did not want to waste too much time on it, and it broke parts of the system that have long been working OK.